# Is it possible to upgrade iOS without connecting the device to a computer?

Tags: itunes, iphone, ios

Is it possible to upgrade the iOS version and apps on an iPhone without connecting it to a computer and going through iTunes?

Comment: iOS can do over the air upgrade now. You do not need to connect to a computer for example, upgrading from 5.01 to 5.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Devs still have to upgrade through iTunes, Xcode only lets you put other apps on your phone. So no, there really isn't another way.

Comment: You do not need to connect to the computer to update your apps, though, since they can be updated from the iPhone AppStore. Large apps can be updated as long as you're on WiFi. But no, no way to update the iOS itself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can connect it to an Apple computer running Xcode and upgrade it there. But most non-developers would find that more horrible, not less.

Comment: @Dan, I *don't* want to connect to Apple computer.

Comment: @Ngu: then connect to a Windows computer and use iTunes, or be happy with the OS version you're running. Those are your options.

Comment: @Dan, in fact I want the software upgraded without connecting to any physical machine.

Comment: @Ngu: That simply isn't possible. You are *required* to physically connect to update the OS.

Comment: Downvoted for truth. Nice.

Comment: @Dan I have no idea who downvoted you, but the question clearly states: "without connecting it to a computer” and your answer said: “you can connect it to an Apple computer”. The downvote is deserved ;)

Comment: @Martin: It said "without connecting it to a computer and iTunes". My answer is "You can connect it to a computer and use Xcode if you want, but you do have to connect it with a computer."

Comment: @Dan: you’re nitpicking… ;)

Comment: @Martin - You wouldn't be the first to say so. ;)